# Как правильно записать условия if elif в одной строке

Tags: python

Как правильно проверять несколько условий, например `if` и `else` указывается следующим образом:

```
x = 15
y = 15 if x == 15 else 0

Вывод [1]: 15
```

Но как проверить несколько условий `if` и `elif` ?
Что то типа:

```
x = 15
```

`y =` Условие 1: `15 if x == 15` Условие 2: `10 elif x == 10 else 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
y = x if x in (15, 10) else 0
```

Больше чем 1 `if` в той же самой строке путает.

Comment: А как быть если надо проверить такие условия: `x = 15`  `y = 'x Больше' if x > 15 else 'x Меньше' if x < 15 else 'x Равно'` ?

Comment: @u1516512562156, это уже другой вопрос — вы можете представить его в форме нового вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде этот ответ будет правильный, но если у кого то есть лучшее решение, пишите.

```
x = 15
y = 15 if x == 15 else 10 if x == 10 else 0

Вывод [1]: 15
```

Answer (score -1):

Надеюсь правильно.[Исправлено]

```
x = 15
y = 15 
if x == 15:
else: 0
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Теперь ошибка *«IndentationError: expected an indented block»* - не было бы лучше проверить ваш код перед его опубликованием?